# how to extract string between two characters in iOS in NSMutablestring?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

ForExample:
String is---book
I want "book". Because Second time it will change to another thing.So i am not using NSRange.

Any Solution?
Thanks

Comment: You need to be more specific, and show what you have tried, but from what little information you have provided, my suggestion would be to look at regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *array = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"---"];
NSString *bookString = array[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but you may need to use this:

```
NSString* myString = [myPrevString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"---" withString:@""];
```